# iText7 Single Cell spliting in two pages after page break

Tags: itext, itext7

As you can see below, the same cell got splitted in two pages... But I need them in the same page, how can I do that?

I tried to use "SetHeight" in cell but no success...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

`new Cell().SetKeepTogether(true)`

Comment: Oh... That's true... I know that but I was using it in table and It wasn't working... Of course... Thanks a lot...

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help